# How to display the countdown time for all users

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I am building a flutter auction application, I am stuck at the countdown time of an auction product so I use firebase realtime database. I have to make sure all users see the countdown at the same time. Please help me whether it's just a keyword to search for, a similar example or something that can help me. And I can use nodejs to assist.

[image]

This is my database, I want when a user posts a product of theirs, the time countdown, and I get that data to display it on the screen. Where do I put that countdown timer? In flutter or firebase.

Comment: Your previous question was closed because it was too broad. Instead of reposting the exact same, please edit your previous question to address the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to store a `deadline` value of a specific datetime, instead of updating your database every second. In the Flutter application, you can implement a countdown locally by using a [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) that updates the time remaining.

This will prevent you from overloading your network traffic, and will continue to work when the connection is lost for a brief moment.

Comment: Thanks so much, but when doing that, can the 2 other users see the same amount of time count down? Because my project desires that all users can see the same countdown time and will end when the time is up.

Comment: time left = deadline - current time. Just create a new Date() to get the current time on the device